# Arrayformula with Vlookup matching Data in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to use an ArrayFormula along with Vlookup with a range to match the data from another Worksheet. In my demo, the source sheet with Col B with `orange` and which is Col A is `Stack` but the destination sheet is not matching where `orange` exists. I can't understand where is my fault.

I have tried but it's wrong pulled.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B:B,IMPORTRANGE("13UCvlMfCse9A_fyVOPlQiwL6JADKZ3O2kMjUfznI-q0", "Source!A:B")},1))
```

[Worksheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PBnTE2i3l0ajLsm9ve9FFq2Xz_CXBg_fQTUOsKhv0ns/edit#gid=0)

I am expecting in the destination sheet that Col A matches Col B.

Comment: Are your search keys in column B or A? Are your search results in column C or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using VLOOKUP, the first column of the range must be the search column. And you shouldn't omit the last parameter if you are looking for an exact match.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B:B,QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("13UCvlMfCse9A_fyVOPlQiwL6JADKZ3O2kMjUfznI-q0", "Source!A:B")),"SELECT Col2, Col1"),2,0)))
```

### update

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B:B,MAP({2,1},LAMBDA(col,INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("13UCvlMfCse9A_fyVOPlQiwL6JADKZ3O2kMjUfznI-q0", "Source!A:B"),,col))),2,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you check one thing, when the value is numeric, it does not work. See my demo plz.

Comment: see updated formula.

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic array formula `MAP()`, try-

```
=MAP(B1:INDEX(B1:B,COUNTA(B1:B)),LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(QUERY(INDEX(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("13UCvlMfCse9A_fyVOPlQiwL6JADKZ3O2kMjUfznI-q0", "Source!A:B"))),"select Col1 where Col2='" & x & "'"),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution is working. @ztiaa also made it shortly but Numatic is not working with his solution.

Comment: @Stella My one should work for numeric also. `B1:INDEX(B1:B,COUNTA(B1:B))` this one is better as it only works on cells, those have data. It it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it).